Getting old account notifications if getting notification form signal r how to clear plugin of notification
we create a flutter app for communication on open app we are getting notification , i want facing issue if account logged out then getting notification.
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
AndroidInitializationSettings androidSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
android: androidSettings
);
void showNotification(
{required int id, required String fromUser, required String detail}) {
AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        "notifications-something-mail", "something-mail-notifications",
        priority: Priority.max, importance: Importance.max);
NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
    NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
notificationsPlugin.show(id, fromUser, detail, notificationDetails);

}
This is notification getting code
when we logged out
await notificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
if we logged out then getting previous account notification how and why please give me solution.
